# Monodevelop+WebApp+Selenium+NUnit: How to approach?

Tags: asp.net, selenium, nunit, monodevelop

I am starting an ASP.Net application in MonoDevelop (blank slate, hobby). I recently used Selenium on a Java based project for a client so thought I would start implementing some testing right from the get go in this project.

I have a solution with two projects: "Website", and "Website Tests". Unfortunately, I can only run one project at a time. The Website Tests always fail because the website is not running.

Is there a way around this, or am I going in the wrong direction?

Updated Details:

1. Confirmed WebsiteTests is set as a "Library"

   - Project Options -> General -> Build -> Compile Target == Library
2. Exact steps taken

   1. Select: "Website" Project
   2. Select: Run with Debugging

      - Verify site is running
   3. Select: View -> Pads -> Unit Tests
   4. Select: Login -> TestTest (just a blank test, no contents)

      - RESULT: pop-up "An application is already running and will have to be stopped. Do you wish to continue?"
      - EXPECTED: ability to run tests

Running in separate MonoDevelop instances also has the same problem. This is unfortunate as it makes it impossible to step through your tests *and* site (have to choose one).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. The website will always been running with IIS unless you explicitly stop it.

Comment: I'm not running it through IIS, I'm running it through MonoDevelop's built in XSP handling

Comment: It sounds like you have added two web projects to your solution. Can you verify that the unit tests project is a class library?

Comment: @Malice, have added some details to the OP

Comment: @Kavius: Sorry, I can't help much more. I don't use Mono or Ubuntu so I can't have a go at reproducing the behaviour.

Comment: @Malice thanks for taking the time at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selenium+Mono is a non-viable solution.

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=5258

Also, MonoDevelop (on Ubuntu) does not appear to have the ability to run multiple processes. This appears to extend to multiple instances of MonoDevelop.

As a work around, you can run the NUnit-Gui separately. Keep the NUnit GUI open as you develop the tests. This is a little old-school, but it works.

1. Open Test Project
2. Make changes to project
3. Compile
4. Switch to NUnit GUI window
5. Run Tests

This still doesn't work as the current Mono+Selenium stack can only run one test at a time. The test project needs to be shutdown and restarted between test runs.